# Why can't you start postgres in docker using "service postgres start"?

Tags: postgresql, docker

All the [tutorials](http://zaiste.net/2013/08/docker_postgresql_how_to/) point out to running postgres in the format of

```
docker run -d -p 5432 \
  -t <your username>/postgresql \
  /bin/su postgres -c '/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/bin/postgres \
    -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.2/main \
    -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.2/main/postgresql.conf'
```

Why can't we in our Docker file have:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/etc/init.d/postgresql-9.2", "start"]
```

And simply start the container by

```
docker run -d psql
```

Is that not the purpose of Entrypoint or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the difference is that the init script provided in `/etc/init.d` is *not* an entry point.  Its purpose is quite different; to get the entry point started, in the background, and then report on the success or failure to the caller.  that script causes a `postgres` process, usually indirectly via `pg_ctl`, to be started, detached from the controlling terminal.

for docker to work best, it needs to run the application directly, attached to the docker process.  that way it can usefully and generically terminate it when the user asks for it, or quickly discover and respond to the process crashing.

Answer (score 1):

Exemplify that IfLoop said.

Using CMD into Dockerfiles:

```
USE postgres 
CMD ["/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/bin/postgres", "-D", "/var/lib/postgresql/9.2/main", "-c", "config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.2/main/postgresql.conf"]
```

To run:

```
$docker run -d -p 5432:5432 psql
```

Watching PostgeSQL logs:

```
$docker logs -f POSTGRES_CONTAINER_ID
```